# Java: An array inside of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering if I could have an array inside of an array? I can't think of a way to explain it.

```
        if (numOfPlayers >= 2) {
          this.config.getString("Tribute_one_spawn");
          String[] onecoords = this.config.getString("Tribute_one_spawn").split(",");
          Player Tribute_one = (Player)this.Playing.get(0);
          World w = p.getWorld();
          double x = Double.parseDouble(onecoords[0]);
          double y = Double.parseDouble(onecoords[1]);
          double z = Double.parseDouble(onecoords[2]);
          Location oneloc = new Location(w, x, y, z);
          Tribute_one.teleport(oneloc);
          this.Frozen.add(Tribute_one);
          Tribute_one.setFoodLevel(20);
          this.config.getString("Tribute_two_spawn");
          String[] twocoords = this.config.getString("Tribute_two_spawn").split(",");
          Player Tribute_two = (Player)this.Playing.get(1);
          World twow = p.getWorld();
          double twox = Double.parseDouble(twocoords[0]);
          double twoy = Double.parseDouble(twocoords[1]);
          double twoz = Double.parseDouble(twocoords[2]);
          Location twoloc = new Location(twow, twox, twoy, twoz);
          Tribute_two.teleport(twoloc);
          this.Frozen.add(Tribute_two);
          Tribute_two.setFoodLevel(20);
        }
        if (numOfPlayers() >= 3) {
          this.config.getString("Tribute_three_spawn");
          String[] coords = this.config.getString("Tribute_three_spawn").split(",");
          Player Tribute_three = (Player)this.Playing.get(2);
          World w = p.getWorld();
          double x = Double.parseDouble(coords[0]);
          double y = Double.parseDouble(coords[1]);
          double z = Double.parseDouble(coords[2]);
          Location loc = new Location(w, x, y, z);
          Tribute_three.teleport(loc);
          this.Frozen.add(Tribute_three);
          Tribute_three.setFoodLevel(20);
        }
```

As you can see, I have to make a new array each in an if else ladder for every player. Instead of making 48 if statements is there a way I could alter the variable name of the coords Array to put it in a for loop with a counter incrementing the name of the array. Well that was a confusing way to explain it but that's the best I can do.

Comment: While is completely possible to have an array of arrays, it is usually better practice to create a new class to more accurately represent your data.

Comment: You're going to have to try harder to find a better way of explaining your problem. 1 line question description and 20 lines of code is not a good question and will have answers that are more like comments or all over the place. Please narrow it down.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes, you can declare an array like `String[][] playerCoords`, However I would suggest looking at the [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface, as it may be more descriptive of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure if I understand you correctly, but you might want to do something like a two-dimensional array. Have a look here:

http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1162

It's allocated like this:

```
double[][] a2 = new double[10][5];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap you code in for loop,provided that you can rename your config variables:

```
for (int i=1;i<numOfPlayers;i++) {
          String[] onecoords = this.config.getString().split(",");
          Player Tribute_i = (Player)this.Playing.get(i-1);
          World w = p.getWorld();
          double x = Double.parseDouble(onecoords[0]);
          double y = Double.parseDouble(onecoords[1]);
          double z = Double.parseDouble(onecoords[2]);
          Location oneloc = new Location(w, x, y, z);
          Tribute_i.teleport(oneloc);
          this.Frozen.add(Tribute_i);
          Tribute_i.setFoodLevel(20);
}
```

Yor config variables will be to be named Tribute_1_spawn,Tribute_2_spawn and so on...
If you need to further use Player objects, you can save them in an array or other data structure.